# Allow from env with mod_rewrite not mod_setenvif in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite, setenv

I am trying to control access to testing sites/hosts but not the production site using .htaccess and Apache 2.2. I am using mod_rewrite to detect the host name and set some environment variables used to control various aspects of the site but can not leverage this for controlling access. I can only control access with mod_setenvif.

I can detect the host and set environment variables. (Simplified.)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}                        test\..*
RewriteRule ^ -                                 [ENV=requireAuth:1,ENV=...]
```

I then later try to use it for controlling access.

```
AuthType     Basic
AuthName     "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile /file/location/.htpasswd

Order        Deny,Allow
Deny         from all
Satisfy      any
Require      valid-user
Allow        from env=!requireAuth
```

This does not work. Removing the not (!) forces every site to have a password which is not acceptable.

I tried a couple of variations using mod_setenvif and only requireAuth2 works.

```
SetEnvIf     HOST                               "test.+" requireAuth2
SetEnvIf     requireAuth                        ".+" requireAuth3
SetEnvIf     %{ENV:requireAuth}                 ".+" requireAuth4
```

I dump the request using phpinfo() and only see requestAuth and requestAuth2.

I rather not have to redo my host checking logic because I have many different host names and many different environment variables. I also like the idea of defaulting to access and having a single env=! test. Rather error on granting access than denying access.

Any suggestions?

Thank, Wes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `mod_setenv`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^test\. requireAuth

AuthType     Basic
AuthName     "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile /file/location/.htpasswd

Order        Deny,Allow
Deny         from all
Satisfy      any
Require      valid-user
Allow        from env=!requireAuth
```

Comment: That is my fall back approach but I am trying to use the environment variables set by `mod_rewrite` similar to the way I am setting `requireAuth3` and `requireAuth4`. I think I may be fighting a loosing battle because `SetEnvIf` and `Allow` are probably being processed before `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: That is true `mod_rewrite` is invoked after `mod_setenv` and `mod_authz`. That's the reason env variables created in `mod_rewrite` cannot be used in `Allow from`