# Apache 2.2 Allow from env=_variable_

Tags: apache, apache2.2, setenvif

I have an Apache 2.2 set up with LDAP Authorization, which is working fantastically as expected, and have also made it so that I can bypass Authentication when accessing it locally.

`Allow from` *localIP* *hostnameA* *hostnameB*, etc...

If I `curl` from the server, I don't get any Auth Required.  So all good and working as expected.

What I need now is to make one particular URL to also bypass authorisation.

I have tried all the usual solution of using `SetEnvIf`;

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/calendar/export" bypassauth=true`
Allow from env=bypassauth IP_ADDRESS HOSTNAME_A HOSTNAME_B
```

But this is just not working!!

1. Local access is still unrestricted, but remotely it is not (no change there)
2. If I dump out my server environment variables on that URL's script, I can see my `bypassauth` variable is being passed.

I just cannot for the life of me figure out why the `Allow from env=bypassauth` part is not working, while it still obeys the additional directive parameters.

*I also* tried another suggestion, using the Location directive;

```
<Location /calendar/export>
  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
  AuthType None

  SetEnv WTF 123
</Location>
```

Again, I can see my new environmental variable (`WTF`) appear on this URL (when I dumped the server envs in the script), so I know that the `SetEnv` and `SetEnvIf` directives are working.

Is there anything I'm missing (any Apache2.2 quirks?), as all the solutions I've seen so far just are not working.  It's as if my `Allow from` changes are having no effect after restarting Apache.  I'm starting to feel my sanity slip.

Is there also a particular order when writing the directives for `Satisfy Any`, `Order allow, deny` and the `Auth*` directives, which might be effecting this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to figure it out!!  :)

Seems my url was being processed by `mod_rewrite` (my environmental variable being prefixed by `REWRITE_` should have rung alarm bells), which according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094842/4800587, the `mod_rewrite` is performed AFTER our `SetEnvIf` and `Allow` directives.

Anyway, long story short;  I used the rewritten/final URL and the `Location` section to bypass authentication using the `Allow any` directive.  So I changed...

```
<Location "/calendar/export">
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

to..

```
<Location "/calendar/index.php/export">
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

which is the final URL (after rewrite), and now works.